# Not Equal To operator not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

SP:

```
INNER JOIN StudentSubjectMapping SS ON SM.StudentID=SS.StudentID  
WHERE SM.CourseID=@CourseID OR @CourseID=0
  AND SM.ClassID=@ClassID OR @ClassID=0
  AND SM.ClassSectionID=@ClassSectionID OR @ClassSectionID=0
  AND SD.StudentID <> SS.StudentID
```

Comment: what is SD.StudentID....SD

Comment: OR is prior to AND..

Comment: When using OR you just have to be very careful how you use it otherwise the results will be unexpected.

Comment: StudentID in another table.

Comment: But its working with, SD.StudentID=SS.StudentID

Comment: @Jithin , use LEFT JOIN , kindly see my sample below on the answer

Answer (score 4):

Try to add brackets `()` in following:

```
WHERE (SM.CourseID=@CourseID OR @CourseID=0)
      AND
      (SM.ClassID=@ClassID OR @ClassID=0)
      AND
      (SM.ClassSectionID=@ClassSectionID OR @ClassSectionID=0)
      AND
      SD.StudentID<>SS.StudentID
```

Comment: @Jithin what not working? Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: At search click i need to show StudentIDs those are not in SS.StudentID.

Comment: @Jithin , use `LEFT JOIN` , kindly see my sample below on the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead

```
    LEFT JOIN StudentSubjectMapping SS ON SM.StudentID=SS.StudentID  
    WHERE SM.CourseID=@CourseID OR @CourseID=0
      AND SM.ClassID=@ClassID OR @ClassID=0
      AND SM.ClassSectionID=@ClassSectionID OR @ClassSectionID=0
      AND SS.StudentID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `NOT IN` to select those `StudentIDs` that doesn't exist in `StudentSubjectMapping`

```
INNER JOIN StudentSubjectMapping SS ON SM.StudentID=SS.StudentID  
WHERE (SM.CourseID=@CourseID OR @CourseID=0)
  AND (SM.ClassID=@ClassID OR @ClassID=0)
  AND (SM.ClassSectionID=@ClassSectionID OR @ClassSectionID=0)
  AND (SD.StudentID NOT IN (SELECT StudentID FROM StudentSubjectMapping))
```

Comment: Almost right. No need to use INNER JOIN. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the support. Answer:

```
WHERE
    (SM.CourseID=@CourseID OR @CourseID=0)
    AND
    (SM.ClassID=@ClassID OR @ClassID=0)
    AND
    (SM.ClassSectionID=@ClassSectionID OR @ClassSectionID=0)
    AND
    SM.StudentID NOT IN (SELECT StudentID FROM StudentSubjectMapping)
```

Comment: Yea, and for the record: Review SQL Operator Precedence; at least AND & OR ;)